# Where is -No Value- coming from in \NewCommandEnvironment?

Tags: environments, latex3, xparse

The code below produces `-No Value-` as the initial output. Why?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{intfig} { > { \SplitArgument { 2 } { , } } m O{} }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \intfig_manditoryargs #1

    string\ is\ \l_intfig_astring_str \\
    height\ is\ \fp_eval:n { \l_intfig_height_fp }\\

    \group_end:
}{}

\str_new:N \l_intfig_astring_str
\fp_new:N \l_intfig_height_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\intfig_manditoryargs}{ m m }
{
  % Side question: why are the braces required? Without the braces, the
  % variable is set to only the first character.
  \str_set:Nn \l_intfig_astring_str { #1 }
  \fp_set:Nn \l_intfig_height_fp  { #2 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{intfig}{random string,45.3}[ignoreme]
  random body
\end{intfig}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the specification `\SplitArgument{2}{,}`, LaTeX is expecting *at most* two commas in the argument (at brace level zero) and will pass them as a triple `{...}{...}{...}`.

So if you pass `a,b,c` you'll get `{a}{b}{c}`. If there are fewer than two commas, the braces will be filled in with `-NoValue-`.

You probably want `\SplitArgument{1}{,}`

Answer (score -1):

I was too quick with that question. The answer is that \SplitArgument takes the number of TOKENS over which to split -- commas in the example above. So, if you want two ARGUMENTS, then there will be only one TOKEN.

That's reasonable and it makes sense, but it's such an obvious pitfall that the `xparse` documentation should point it out.

Comment: But it does, doesn't it? usrguide3.pdf says  "This processor splits the argument given at each occurrence of the ⟨ tokens ⟩ up to a maximum of ⟨ number ⟩ tokens (thus dividing the input into ⟨ number ⟩ + 1 parts)."

Comment: I'm a mathematician, so I'm used to "close reading," but even so, that's expecting a bit much. I was thinking of something along the lines of {\textbf Pay attention everyone. This doesn't work the way you probably think it does.}